# In Spelunky HD what secret levels are there and how do I find them?

Tags: spelunky-hd

In the 360 version of Spelunky (not the PC version, which is different) what secret levels are there and how do you get to them?

Answer (score 15):

There are six found so far, but there may be more. I've only found the first four, so credit has to go to [Todd Schlickbernd](http://www.xblafans.com/author/emessai) and SnapDragon for the last two.

- **Black Market** - there's a hidden door (use bombs or the mattock) on most levels that goes here. The huge eye (from the gold key chest in the mines) helps find them.
  [image: Udjat Eye]
- **Worm** - on any level with one of those floating pink spiky things that you can jump on (mostly in the jungle levels) throw a stunned damsel so that they stick to it and then jump on yourself. After a few seconds you will both be swallowed by the worm. Strangely, you still get the kiss for doing this :-)
  [image: Worm]
- **Haunted Castle** - when you get the "Dead are Restless" message at the start of a jungle level keep an eye out for a large grave with a buried skeleton wearing a crown. Destroy the ground below the skeleton king to find a secret door. Also look out for any graves with ASH written on them - destroy the ground below for a boomstick :-D
  [image: Haunted Castle]
- **Mothership** - on the final ice level there's two exits. The one at the top goes to the mothership. You will need lots of rope or the jetpack.
  [image: Mothership]
- **City of Gold** - really hard to get to this one:
  [image: City of Gold]

  1. You must get the eye from the mines, I don't think finding the Black Market otherwise is enough.
  2. You must get to the Black Market and either buy the golden ankh or kill all the shopkeepers.
     [image: Ankh]
  3. On one of the ice levels (3rd section) there's a giant stone head with an ankh symbol on it. You must die near this, without using bombs.
  4. You will appear inside the stone head next to a golden pointy crown
     [image: Hedjet]
  5. In the temple area kill an Anubis, they will drop the Sceptre:
     [image: Sceptre]
  6. Finally walk over the large golden block with a hole in it - if you have everything
- **Hell** - I haven't made it here yet, so I'm going by [the guides of others](http://www.xblafans.com/spelunky-guide-secrets-and-unlockables-51196.html):

  1. Get to the City of Gold
  2. Recover the Necronomicon:
     [image: Necronomicon]
  3. This will spawn a new Anubis. This one spawns lots of red skeletons. You must kill him.
  4. During Olmec, the final boss,move around until the book starts as it's face the most. (it starts slow ,then speeds up as you get closer). Defeat Olmec over that spot. There will be a door. This door has no step, so jetpacks or capes make no difference. You must use Olmec's face as a step as he sinks into the lava to get to hell. This is impossible without the book, as the door will not appear if you do not have it.

Comment: When trying to get to the City of Gold, dying anywhere in the Ice Caves level containing the giant stone head will revive you inside the head, regardless of how or where you died (although explosions and being crushed seems to occasionally destroy your jetpack). Also, when Olmec falls into the lava below the entrance to Hell, do note that he continues to sink and you have a window of 1-2 seconds to enter the door. While waiting to get in, Magma Men can jump out of the lava and push you in, so careful!!

Answer (score 2):

Real last step:

During Olmec, the final boss,move around until the book writhes at it's face the most. (it starts slow ,then speeds up as you get closer). Defeat Olmec over that spot. There will be a door. This door has no step, so jetpacks or capes make no difference. You must use Olmec's face as a step as he sinks into the lava to get to hell. This is impossible without the book, as the door will not appear if you do not have it.

The worm is much larger than a standard level. In a pool of acid inside is the Crysknife. It one-hit-kills ANYTHING. Be sure to retrieve it. Also, in the green background decoration with a silhouette, whip it to free a secret character.

At the top inside of the haunted castle is a secret character. Whip the coffin to free him.

The mothership is reverse and drops you off at 3-3, although it appears at 3-4. Within are alien lords and the alien queen, whom guards a very destructive plasma cannon.Break open the distinct alien pod in the background to unlock a secret character.

The black market entrance does NOT appear on most levels.Only one chance to enter appears on 2-1, 2-2, or 2-3.